# Powershell Chrome Zoom

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, batch-file

I have the below code working on my PS1. How do i change the zoom of the chrome window which is opened.

```
start chrome --app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(0,1080);window.resizeTo(960,540);window.location='<URL>;</script></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a programmatic way to do this to my knowledge and so your PowerShell script will have to pretend to be a user that brings the Chrome window to the foreground and presses the required keys.

In the script below, I find windows that matches the phrase "Google Chrome", takes the first one and then sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> keypresses so that it zooms in twice from the default.

Those key strokes are expressed as `^0^=^=` in the script. Similarly, you could use `^0^-^-` to zoom out. For more information about how to specify the keys to send into a window, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
$titleMatch = "Google Chrome"
$keys = "^0^=^="

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

# This C# fragment makes available a class that can set the foreground window
# since this is not a built-in feature in PowerShell.

Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class SelectWindow {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@

# Find the processes where the main window has a title that matches our query.

$processes = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -match $titleMatch }

if ($processes) {

  # Get the main window handle of the first matching process.

  $windowHandle = $processes[0].MainWindowHandle

  # Bring that window to the front and send the keys to it.

  [SelectWindow]::SetForegroundWindow($windowHandle) | Out-Null
  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($keys)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Don Cruickshank's method using p\invoke, you could also use the `AppActivate` method from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` to make Chrome the active window.

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 
 Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
 $ID = (Start-Process chrome.exe -PassThru).id 
 Sleep 1
 [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate([Int32]$ID)
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^0^=^=")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a temporary size change then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to reset.

If you want to increase the font size in the Javascript console, you need add some specific size like:

```
.source-code {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.console-prompt {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```